# ftp script in bash

Tags: bash, ftp

I have the following script that pushes files to remote location:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
HOST1='a.b.c.d'
USER1='load'
PASSWD1='load'
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`
DATE2=`date +%Y%m%d%H`
DATE3=`date +%Y%m%d`
FTPLOGFILE=/logs/Done.$DATE2.log
D_FOLDER='/dir/load01/input'

PUTFILE='file*un'
ls $PUTFILE | while read file
do
  echo "${file} transfered at $DATE" >> /logs/$DATE3.log
done

ftp -n -v $HOST1 <<SCRIPT >> ${FTPLOGFILE} 2>&1
quote USER $USER1
quote PASS $PASSWD1
cd $D_FOLDER
ascii
prompt off
mput /data/file*un 
quit
SCRIPT

mv *un test/

ls test/*un | awk '{print("mv "$1" "$1)}' | sed 's/\.un/\.processed/2' |sh
rm *unl
```

I am getting this error output:

```
200 PORT command successful.
553 /data/file1.un: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
200 PORT command successful.
```

Answer (score 5):

Some improvements:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
HOST1='a.b.c.d'
USER1='load'
PASSWD1='load'
read Y m d H M <<<$(date "+%Y %m %d %H %M")    # only one call to date
DATE='$Y$m$d$H$M'
DATE2='$Y$m$d$H'
DATE3='$Y$m$d'
FTPLOGFILE=/logs/Done.$DATE2.log
D_FOLDER='/dir/load01/input'

PUTFILE='file*un'
for file in $PUTFILE    # no need for ls
do
  echo "${file} transfered at $DATE"
done >> /logs/$DATE3.log    # output can be done all at once at the end of the loop.

ftp -n -v $HOST1 <<SCRIPT >> ${FTPLOGFILE} 2>&1
quote USER $USER1
quote PASS $PASSWD1
cd $D_FOLDER
ascii
prompt off
mput /data/file*un 
quit
SCRIPT

mv *un test/

for f in test/*un    # no need for ls and awk
do
  mv "$f" "${f/%.un/.processed}"
done

rm *unl
```

I recommend using lower case or mixed case variables to reduce the chance of name collisions with shell variables.

Are all those directories really directly off the root directory?

Answer (score 0):

Ftp to the the remote site and execute the ftp commands by hand. When the error occurs, look around to see what is the cause. (Use "help" if you don't know the ftp command line.)

Probably the `/data` directory does not exist. has anyone reorganized the upload directory recently, or maybe moved the root directory of the ftp server?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with scripting an FTP session is that FTP believes it has executed itself correctly if it reports errors to stdout. Consequently, it's devilishly hard to pick up errors, since it will only return a fail on something catastrophic. If you need anything more than the most simple of command lists, you should really be using something like expect or a java or perl program that can easily test the result of each action.

That said, you *can* run the ftp as a coprocess, or set it up so that it runs in background with it's stdin and stdout fitted to named pipes, or some structure like that where you can read and parse the output from one command before deciding what to pass in for the next one.

A read loop that cycles on a case statement which tests for known responses and behaves accordingly is a passably acceptable all-bash version. if you always terminate every command block with something like an `image` command that returns a fixed and known value, you can scan for known errors, and check for the return from that command in the case statement, and when you get the "sentinal" return loop back and read the next input. This makes for a largish and fairly complicated shell script, though.

Also, you need to test that when you get (for example) a `5[0-9][0-9] *)` return it isn't actually "553 bytes*" because ftp screws you that way too.

Apologies for the length of the answer without including a code example - I just wanted to mention some ideas and caveats that wouldn't fit readably in a comment.